# Sync Framework Synchronization of filtered data on different office locations

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using Microsoft Sync Framework. It is working fine. But what I need is:
I have 10 centers at different locations. Data of all the centers is available at one centralized locations. I am synchronizing the data of one center with FilterClause and another center data with another FilterClause. It does not show any error but sync same data at all locations; instead of relevant center data.

What I am using is : Microsoft Sync Framework, C# and Sql Server Database:

Here is coding:

```
try
        {
            var serverConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conOnline"].ConnectionString);
            var clientConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conLocal"].ConnectionString);
            string scopeName = tableName + CenterCode + "Scope";

            var serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn);
            if (!serverProvision.ScopeExists(scopeName))
            {
                var serverScopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(scopeName);
                var serverTableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(tableName, serverConn);
                serverScopeDesc.Tables.Add(serverTableDesc);
                foreach (string key in KeyNames)
                {
                    serverScopeDesc.Tables[tableName].Columns[key].IsPrimaryKey = true;
                }
                serverProvision.PopulateFromScopeDescription(serverScopeDesc);
                serverProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.CreateOrUseExisting);

                //filter
                try
                {
                    serverProvision.Tables[tableName].AddFilterColumn("cen_cd");
                    serverProvision.Tables[tableName].FilterClause = "[side].[cen_cd]='" + CenterCode + "'";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                serverProvision.Apply();
            }

            var clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn);
            if (!clientProvision.ScopeExists(scopeName))
            {
                var clientScopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(scopeName);
                var clientTableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(tableName, serverConn);
                clientScopeDesc.Tables.Add(clientTableDesc);
                foreach (string key in KeyNames)
                {
                    clientScopeDesc.Tables[tableName].Columns[key].IsPrimaryKey = true;
                }
                clientProvision.PopulateFromScopeDescription(clientScopeDesc);
                clientProvision.Apply();
            }

            var syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();
            //setup providers
            var remoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, serverConn);
            syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = remoteProvider;

            var localProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, clientConn);
            syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = localProvider;
            syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;
            var syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = "Error:\n" + ex.Message + "\n\nInner Exception:\n" + ex.InnerException;
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check on your server how many *_selectchanges stored procedure do you have against the table and if they have a filter?

looking at your code, you're not using scope filter templates (creating a template scope with a filter and creating scopes based on the template using different filter values).

and since you didn't specify SetCreateProceduresForAdditionalScopeDefault, all your scopes are re-using the same _selectchanges SP instead of creating a new one for each scope.

Comment: Could you please provide my some codes examples of material from where I can get this issue resolved...

Comment: already mentioned what you need to add - SetCreateProceduresForAdditionalScopeDefault

Comment: I am getting this error while mentioning SetCreateProceduresForAdditionalScopeDefault(CreateOrUseExisting):

        Cannot alter CreateProceduresForAdditionalScope when a scope is being created from a template

Comment: you can't use SetCreateProceduresForAdditionalScopeDefault when you're using a template. the instruction above is for the existing code you have. if you have changed to template, you dont have to use it because you're not going to create a new stored procedures for every new scope you create from the template. the scopes based on a template all share the same store procedure. Check out this to understand more about provisioning: https://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/sync-framework-provisioning/